# Faster c# image processing

Tags: c#, c++, image, image-processing

I have a pretty extensive c++ image processing library and I have been working on a c# project but I cannot seem to be able to get the c# to be anywhere near as fast as the c++. My c++ takes 149ms to process setting the entire image white while the c# takes 1071ms to do the same.

Here is my c++ code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < image->height; y++)
    {
        unsigned char * srcPixel = (unsigned char*)image->mImageData + (y * image->width);

        for (int x = 0; x < image->width; x++)
        {
            srcPixel[0] = 255;
            srcPixel[1] = 255;
            srcPixel[2] = 255;
            srcPixel[3] = 255;
            srcPixel += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

mImageData is a struct of unsigned chars

```
struct mImageData
{
    unsigned char alpha;
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
}
```

And this is the c# code I am using. This is the fastest I have been able to get this one.

```
frame = new Bitmap(3840, 2160);
BitmapData bitmapData12 = frame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
            frame.Width, frame.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);


var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
unsafe
{
    int pixelBytes = 4;
    int paddingBytes = bitmapData12.Stride % pixelBytes;

    byte* location1 = (byte*)bitmapData12.Scan0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        location1 = (byte*)bitmapData12.Scan0;
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData12.Height; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmapData12.Width; ++x)
            {
                location1[0] = 255;
                location1[1] = 255;
                location1[2] = 255;
                location1[3] = 255;

                location1 += pixelBytes;
            }

            location1 += paddingBytes;
        }
    }
}

stopwatch.Stop();
var miliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

frame.UnlockBits(bitmapData12);
```

Comment: The C# code looks fine to me. 1) Is the "frame" bitmap in Format32bppArgb format - or is it being converted? 2) You're not measuring from within Visual Studio?

Comment: frame is a "frame = new Bitmap(ResW, ResH);" I am measuring in visual studio using a Datetime start and end. I do the start after the bitmpadata instantiate, right before the unsafe, and then do the end after the end of the unsafe context.

Comment: Running within VS won't give you JIT-optimzed code - so stop that! :-), and use a Stopwatch instead of a DateTime - it is more accurate. The results are odd, anyway...

Comment: Don't benchmark from Visual Studio. Use the release mode, and run it from the .exe. And do enough iterations for your test to be worth it. 4ms is way too low to be accurate. Even 40 is borderline, DateTime ticks change each 16ms only I think. Use the Stopwach class, as Dan said.

Comment: Alrighty, I switched it to a stopwatch and release and made it do a WriteAllLines for the stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds so I could just double click the built exe. I also updated it so it looped through and did the function 100 times. On my c++ I got 357ms, on the c# I got 1071ms

Comment: Why don't you update your question using the details reported in your last comment? It will make it far more accurate.

Comment: good idea, Updated the main question.

Comment: Just guessing and is too lazy to verify for myself: maybe the bitmapData12.Width cannot be properly inlined? You could try to count down from bitmapData12.Width to 0 instead, I always do that myself, but that mostly comes from old habit.

Comment: I'll bet that `std::fill` will beat your C++. CPU bandwidth is measured in Gigabytes per second. 357 ms is insanely slow.

Comment: @MSalters well we don't know his image size, and the measurement is repeated 100 times, so 357 ms could in fact be for gigabytes of memory writes.

Comment: @romkyns: The measurement may cover 100 images, but the result was specified _per image_. And yes, I considered a 4K image - still only 32 MB.

Comment: @MSalters True, the question text states it's per-image, but the code shows it's the total time. Oh well, this hasn't been a top quality question from the start. The OP has now clarified it's a 3830x2160 image (probably meant 3840...)

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with ResW = 3000 and ResH = 3000, to get 900ms processing time. I ran it in Release mode, with the debugger detached.

Observe that this image contains 9 million pixels, each one 4 bytes long. That's 36 MB to fill. We're filling this 100 times, so a total of 3.6 billion bytes to set. My CPU runs at 4.5 GHz, **so it managed to set 3.6 billion bytes in 4 billion clock cycles**.

I'd say that's not too shabby for any language. If I were to shut down all the VMs, background processes and servers on my dev machine (which are currently consuming between 5% and 20% CPU) to run a cleaner measurement, I'd get pretty much exactly one byte set per clock cycle. Of course CPUs can do vastly better - **if** you ask them to perform the right operation. Setting one byte at a time certainly makes it slower.

So C# is really doing this as fast as possible without modifying the algorithm. It's just that C# refuses to optimize past a literal translation of the code, whereas C++ can and will do that. Simply doing what AdamF suggests (use `uint`) already shrinks the time to 300ms in my own tests.

I don't think you've specified what your ResW/ResH are (or I'm blind), so it's still possible that you're not running the code the fastest way possible and something interferes with the measurement.

Comment: The resolution I am running at is 3830x2160. I will update the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit dirty solution but if the size of your image stucture is always the same then maybe you can try to optimize it in this way:

In my tests the speed up is from about 1100ms to 750ms

```
unsafe
{
    int width = bitmapData12.Width;
    for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData12.Height; ++y)
    {
        UInt32* location1 = (UInt32*) (bitmapData12.Scan0 + y*bitmapData12.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            location1[x] = UInt32.MaxValue;
    }
}
```